# Tortoise SVN head root folder name

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using tortoise SVN and I have a directory structure as follows

```
root-1
   folder1svn
   folder2
   folder3
   folder4svn
```

I want to change root-1 to root_1 knowing that root-1 is not an svn folder, without affecting the underlying subfolders.

Please note as well that folder2 and folder3 are not svn folders

Comment: What's the question? Are you asking how to rename a folder?

Comment: yes I want to change root-1 to root_1

Comment: Select the root-1 folder in windows explorer, hit F2, type root_1, then Enter.

Comment: regardless of the sarcastic comment, but I won't be able commit or update any files, there will be a conflict

Comment: Explain the problem better. You're saying that root-1 is not an SVN folder. So what does it have to do with SVN? And if it doesn't have anything to do with SVN, how would renaming it cause any conflict?

Comment: what I know is that tortoise SVN keeps the full directory structure for the checked out repositories, so if I changed the root-1, it will cause a conflict in folder1svn and folder4svn

Comment: No it won't. The location of the working copy doesn't matter, and you can move a working copy to wherever you want, and it will still work fine. Everything SVN needs to know about is in the .svn directory at the root of the working copy, i.e. in folder1svn (first WC) and folder4svn (second WC). And every SVN operation on the WC is done using relative paths starting from the WC root.

Comment: Ok it works so far however my memories with tortoise SVN about changing the directories are really bad.